# my program just crushes, using realloc() in recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree, realloc

I have a problem with this code, I tried to understand what's going on, but I cannot understand why it just crushes. the functions works like I expect for the node->left.

But when the last call of the function ends in the case node->left; the function just crushes, I think because of the reallocated array, I don't know if I'm trying to access a forbidden memory.

I'll explain a little more where I think the problem comes from:we are in the last call of helper(node->left,table,len) before printing the array : consider len = N and node->left!=NULL ==> reallocating table len = N+1, assigning node->data to table[len] and everything is fine, node->left == NULL ==> printing the table and we are done with the helper(node->left,table,N) case; now we are in the helper(node->right,table,N) case; in this case the program just crushes ; it's supposed to reallocate table; and assign node->data to table[N]; and so one ...

By the way : this function tries to print all the Root-leaf paths in a binary tree.

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

void helper(struct node* node,int *table,int len)
{
    if(node == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        table = realloc(table,(len+1)*sizeof(int));
        table[len]=node->data;
        len = len +1;
        if(node->left == NULL && node->right == NULL)
        {
            int cmt=0;
            for(cmt = 0; cmt < len ; cmt++ ){
                    printf("%d ->",table[cmt]);
                }    
        }
        else{
            helper(node->left,table,len);
            helper(node->right,table,len);
        }    
    }
}


void print_rtl(struct node* node) {
    if(NULL == node) return;
    else{
        int *t=malloc(sizeof(int));
        t[0]=node->data;
        int lenght = 1;
        helper(node->left,t,1);
        helper(node->right,t,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: 'I'll explain a little more where I think the problem comes from' - does your debugger support this?

Comment: I don't use a debugger, I'm a C beginner. and I didn't learn how to debug.

Comment: Good time to learn wouldn't you think? What would you say to a carpenter that said I'm a beginner carpenter, I didn't learn how to use a hammer?

Comment: I think so ^^ ; I'll invest the next months to learn new things .

Comment: Consider what value for `table` you're passing down each recursed call of the *left* side. Now consider what value `table` *still has* when you back out a left-recursed call and proceed down the *right* side. If the traversal down a left path performs a `realloc`, how does the *caller* know that ? In short, `table = ...anything...` is not conveyed up the call-stack.

Comment: time spent learning how to use the debugger will not be wasted...

Comment: Beginners need debugging skills even more than experienced developers.  If you cannot debug, you shoud not try and develop software because you don't have a requisite skill.

Comment: I don't develop a software it's just an exercise o_o ; I have already the solution , but I don't to know why my own code doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the thing about [realloc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html): it has the freedom to change not just the size of the allocated memory block, but also its location.  In general, realloc can break any pointers you have that are pointing to objects in the block of memory that was realloced.  When you try to use those pointers later, you will get undefined behavior.

You should either allocate enough memory at the beginning of your program that you won't need to call realloc, or you should redesign your program so you don't need to allocate that memory block in the first place, or you should make your `table` pointer be a global variable so that when you change its value, it gets updated for every function that is using the table.

Right now the problem with your code is that when you call `helper`, it might call realloc and change the location of your table, but it doesn't communicate that change to the caller in any way, so the caller doesn't know where the table is located.

There might be other problems with your code.  If you continue to have trouble, I strongly urge you to produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post that in your next question.  Doing that makes it much easier for someone else to reproduce your problem and find a solution to it that actually works.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell *exactly* what going on because it quite a big mess, but generally... The first thing `helper()` does (after validating `node!=NULL`) is reallocate `table`. That means when you get to the recursion point, `helper(node->left..` will reallocate, and then immediately after `helper(node->right..` will also try to do so, but on an invalid pointer. From there on, it's a wild ride to exceptions...